# Interface method return value of own type

Tags: go, interface

I am trying to make a method which will take structs of a certain type and do operations on them. However, I need to have a method one can call on an instance of the stuct, and it will return objects of that struct's type. I am getting a compile time error because the return type of the type which implements the interface isn't the same as the interface's method return type, but that's because the interface needs to return values of it's own type.

Interface declaration:

```
type GraphNode interface {
    Children() []GraphNode
    IsGoal() bool
    GetParent() GraphNode
    SetParent(GraphNode) GraphNode
    GetDepth() float64
    Key() interface{}
}
```

Type which implements that interface:

```
type Node struct {
    contents []int
    parent   *Node
    lock     *sync.Mutex
}

func (rootNode *Node) Children() []*Node {
...
}
```

Error Message:

```
.\astar_test.go:11: cannot use testNode (type *permutation.Node) as type GraphNode in argument to testGraph.GetGoal:
*permutation.Node does not implement GraphNode (wrong type for Children method)
have Children() []*permutation.Node
want Children() []GraphNode
```

Method to get parent:

```
func (node *Node) GetParent() *Node {
    return node.parent
}
```

The above method fails because it returns a pointer to a node, and the interface returns type GraphNode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`*Node` doesn't implement the `GraphNode` interface because the return type of `Children()` isn't the same as that defined in the interface. Even if `*Node` implements `GraphNode`, you can't use `[]*Node` where `[]GraphNode` is expected. You need to declare `Children()` to return `[]GraphNode`. The elements of a slice of type `[]GraphNode` can be of type `*Node`.

For `GetParent()`, just change it to this:

```
func (node *Node) GetParent() GraphNode {
    return node.parent
}
```

Comment: Should Children's receiver also be of type GraphNode? Otherwise when I have a method that is called on a node and returns the modified node I would need to cast it to the GraphNode interface, which doesn't really make sense.

Comment: No, the receiver should be your actual type as you have it written. That and the other interface method definitions are what make your type an implementation of the interface. For the interface methods that return a value of type `GraphNode`, you can return a value of type `*Node`, since that type implements the interface.

Comment: So to confirm, the issue only occurs when returning slices of Nodes/GraphNodes?

Comment: Your method definitions must match the interface definition exactly (name, argument types, return types). `GetParent` must return `GraphNode`, but within the function, you can return a value of type `*Node`. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: Okay. So in my implementation of the interface, the only place that my type name (Node) should appear in the prototype is in the receiver? Everything else should be of the interface type?

Comment: Yes, that's right. More specifically, everything else (method name, argument types, and return types) must be the same as those in the interface definition.

Comment: Okay. So I think I understand that. Now once I get a GraphNode out of one of these methods, how can I convert it back to a Node? I get an error stating that the type assertion is impossible:

Error: `Node does not implement astar.GraphNode (Children method has pointer receiver)`


Assetion: `testNode.Children()[0].(Node).GetParent().contents`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137303/discussion-between-andy-schweig-and-adrian-smith).