# How to use an interface where one of the methods returns objects of that same interface?

Tags: go

I am still wrapping my head around interfaces in Go, but I am writing a package that will take a graph of structs and print them to stdout as a tree. To do this I have defined an `interface` called `TreeNode` which contains a method `GetChildren` which needs to return a slice of structs implementing `TreeNode`. That way I can recurse down the tree starting with the root. i.e. Here is the full interface definition:

```golang
type TreeNode interface {
    GetName() string
    GetChildren() []TreeNode
}
```

I have heard that it is a best practice to "accept interfaces and return structs". Which makes a lot of sense. However, I start to run into problems when I try to implement those methods on a `struct`. Here is a full example:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

type MyStruct struct {
    Name     string
    Children []*MyStruct
}

type TreeNode interface {
    GetName() string
    GetChildren() []TreeNode
}

func PrintTree(root TreeNode) {
    // Print the nodes recursively
    fmt.Println(root.GetName())
    // etc.
}

func main() {
    child1 := &MyStruct{
        Name: "Child 1",
    }
    child2 := &MyStruct{
        Name: "Child 2",
    }
    root := &MyStruct{
        Name:     "Root",
        Children: []*MyStruct{child1, child2},
    }
    PrintTree(root)
}

func (my_struct *MyStruct) GetName() string {
    return my_struct.Name
}

func (my_struct *MyStruct) GetChildren() []*MyStruct {
    return my_struct.Children
}
```

In the call to `PrintTree` in `main` the compiler complains that

```
cannot use root (type *MyStruct) as type TreeNode in argument to PrintTree:
    *MyStruct does not implement TreeNode (wrong type for GetChildren method)
        have GetChildren() []*MyStruct
        want GetChildren() []TreeNode
```

This is a little surprising since the interface says that `GetChildren()` should return objects that implement `TreeNode` and `*MyStruct` *does* implement `TreeNode`. But clearly there is something I'm missing about how the compiler handles this sort of situation (where the interface type is needed recursively).

If I take the compiler's advice (and the advice of [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42615210/interface-method-return-value-of-own-type)) and change `MyStruct`'s implementation of `GetChildren` to return `[]TreeNode` I get a new compiler error inside the `GetChildren()` implementation saying

```
cannot use my_struct.Children (type []*MyStruct) as type []TreeNode in return argument
```

which is also a surprise. Plus the consensus seems to be that I should return `struct`s from methods instead of returning `interface`s. I could definitely live with returning `[]TreeNode` from that method, but I must have overlooked something because the compiler is not happy.

Go Version: `go version go1.13.8 darwin/amd64`

Comment: If there's only one implementation of `TreeNode`, then drop the interface and used `*MyStruct` directly.  If there's more than one implementation, then see Burak's answer.

Comment: Good point, I was hoping to make it more general-purpose in the long run though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Accept interfaces, return structs" is not a rule, but a practice that makes life easier. However, in this case with your interface definition, you don't have a lot of choices.

You can keep your design, but implement GetChildren:

```
func (my_struct *MyStruct) GetChildren() []TreeNode {
    ret:=make([]TreeNode,0,len(my_struct.Children))
    for _,x:=range my_struct.Children {
        ret=append(ret,x)
    }
    return ret
}
```

This is required because of the strict nature of Go's type system.

Alternatively, you can modify your design a bit:

```
type MyStruct struct {
    Name     string
    Children []TreeNode
}
```

This will require you to use type assertions if you need to access the underlying structs when working with `Children`. However, it will let you build trees with nodes of different types.

Comment: Aha, thank you. I think I'm still figuring out where the duck typing kicks in and where it doesn't. For example, it's not obvious that appending structs to a slice of interface type would be allowed when returning structs from a method that returns an interface type is not allowed.

Comment: The problem here is with arrays. If `T` implements interface `I`, any value of type `T` can be used where an `I` is needed, but that doesn't mean `[]T` can be used where `[]I` is needed, for the simple reason that the memory layouts of those two arrays are different. The first has `T` elements with some arbitrary size, and the second has `I` elements where each element is a pair (pointer, type).